# How to dynamically align two different text sizes on the same line horizontally

Tags: javascript, css

is it possible to use JS to align two different text sizes to be centered on the same line horizontally?

```css
.big {
    font-size: 60px;
}

.small {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span class="big">ABCD.EF</span>
    <span class="small">ABC</span>
</div>
```

Difficult thing is: I need this to be achieved dynamically as ABCD.EF could change to more or less number of characters (ie it could be ABC.DE or A.BC...)

Thanks!

Comment: How did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is flexbox. I recommend checking out [this tutorial](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) to learn how to use it.

If you want to align the items the other way, use `flex-direction: row;`

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.big {
    font-size: 60px;
}

.small {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span class="big">ABCD.EF</span>
    <span class="small">ABC</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is not supported yet in all browsers.  When it finally is, I will rejoice the day.  This is a good solution if you know which browser your users are using.

Comment: @Scott Which browsers are you referring to? It seems to be supported by just about all of them: https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: All of IE has partial support which means you need to be careful about which flexbox features you use.  You may need a vendor prefix too.  IE9 and back all do not support it at all.  Even IE11 seems to have an impact on this exact question if min-height is used.  Referring to: "IE 11 does not vertically align items correctly when min-height is used"

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to the spans.   Try this out:

```css
.big {
    font-size: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.small {
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span class="big">ABCD.EF</span>
    <span class="small">ABC</span>
</div>
```

Or you could target all spans within your parent class, like so:

```
.parent span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```